# Why not install UEFI and BIOS operating systems on same PC?

Tags: boot, installation, bios, uefi

I have read in several places that you should avoid installing UEFI and BIOS OSes, even on different disks. Why?

I need to install a BIOS operating system, and also an UEFI OS, on the same PC. So I am thinking about doing this:

1. Remove all disks except one, install the BIOS OS on the disk
2. Remove all disks except one, install the UEFI OS on this other disk
3. Plugin all disks
4. Upon boot, I should be able to choose between the BIOS or UEFI disks via the boot menu, pressing F11.

This should solve all problems? Or do I have to tinker with BIOS settings before booting a disk? What is the reason it is not recommended to install BIOS and UEFI OSes on different disks?

(For future reference; the reason you should not install UEFI and BIOS operating systems on one disk is this: BIOS OSes requires the disk be formatted MBR style. UEFI OSes requires the disk be formatted GPT style. So you have either a MBR disk or GPT disk, not both. So only one OS will work, the other will not. This is the reason you should not install BIOS and UEFI OSes on the same disk. However, if you install it on different disks, I think if it should work? If not, why?)

Answer (score 1):

Because UEFI and BIOS operate *before* the operating system does any work. It is the core program that runs from ROM to initialise the most basic hardware elements and then run the OS bootloader.

While the OS must install itself in the correct way for the firmware, it is *not* a UEFI or BIOS OS.

UEFI and BIOS provide core system services and is completely separate from the operating system.

UEFI and BIOS are completely distinct and separate system firmwares.

As such the operating system must understand what booted it, BIOS or UEFI, and installing a UEFI OS on a BIOS system is essentially impossible because the methods of handover from firmware to operating system are completely different.

At best if you have a UEFI system firmware with Compatibility Support Module (CSM/BIOS) interface you would be able to go into your firmware, switch the CSM on or off and boot the other OS, but a UEFI firmware cannot launch a BIOS bootloader and neither can a BIOS firmware launch a UEFI bootloader.

Comment: One way I solve this issue is to run older machines as virtual machines. That works very well.

Comment: I would agree, on modern hardware virtual machines are indeed relatively lightweight these days and when direct hardware access is not necessary I would 100% advocate their use over dual booting as it is far simpler and easier to revert back to a "clean" state. Device pass-through may be an option in some of those cases but not all. There are also times when the host OS uses too much resource (memory) and might make a VM unsuitable, particularly on low memory machines.

Comment: @Mokubai, thanx for your clarification, it helps me understands the problem. However, back to my original question. I have a Supermicro X10SAT motherboard. There are no CSM option in the BIOS menu, but it has UEFI. Can I still install BIOS OS on a single disk, and then UEFI OS on another disk - and choose between the disks via boot menu?

I can not run virtual machines for different reasons.

Comment: No. You cannot install an operating system that only understands BIOS booting while in UEFI mode. Some operating systems might be able to set themselves up in either way, but that is typically done at time of installation. It might be better for you to stop beating around the bushes and ask a new question telling us what you are actually trying or wanting to do.

Comment: Ok, what  am I actually trying to do is this:----
I want to install OpenIndiana (an OpenSolaris derivative) and use my Nvidia GTX 1070 Ti driver. The Nvidia Solaris driver only works on BIOS installations, which means OpenIndiana must be installed as BIOS. I also want to have Win10 for gaming, and Win10 only installs on UEFI. So I need BIOS Solaris, and UEFI Win10 on the same PC. How can this be done? ---- You tell me it this setup is very problematic. So I am now considering this instead: Install OpenIndiana. Use KVM and install Win10 using passthrough of GTX1070 Ti for games. Please advise?